# Define fallback value for empty Active Directory attribute in email transport rule?

Tags: outlook, active-directory, html-email, microsoft-exchange

Total rookie here, so sorry if this is a simple or bad question :)

Our organization is using exchange server transport rules to apply email signatures as disclaimers. It's working great for the most part, but I haven't been able to figure out how to define a fallback value for empty Active Directory attributes that we're using to populate the signature. ie- we have several general accounts such as **info@company.com** and there's no unique phone number associated with that profile, so the %%PhoneNumber%% field in that signature just displays as a blank line... but I'd like to define a default fallback phone number for the front office so there's no empty line).

I was hoping there was a simple command to append to that attribute field in the disclaimer html, like %%PhoneNumber;555-555-5555%% so that if the first is blank then it moves on to the second, etc.

I done all the googling I can but must not be using the right terms, or am just out of my depth on this. Thanks for any help!

```
<div style="font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;">

<!-- insert logo -->
<div style="margin-bottom:20px;">
<img style="height:xx; width:xx; border:0;" src="" alt="">
</div>

<!-- insert staff info -->
<span style="text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold;">%%displayName%% </span> <br />
<em>%%title%%</em> <br />
P: %%Phone%% <br />
F: %%Fax%% <br />
<a href="">website</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the value of `PhoneNumber` with a default earlier in the code so that you don't need to do it in Active Directory?

Comment: How would you suggest doing that, @dlsso ?
Just added basic version of how the signature code currently appears in my question post above...

Comment: I'm sorry, I wouldn't be able to tell you that. It depends on the constraints of your project.